# Color grid lines in Julia

Tags: plot, colors, grid, julia

I would like to color the grid lines in a plot. Here is some reproducible code:

```
using Plots
Plots.plot(rand(10))
```

Output:

[image]

Imagine I want to have green grid lines, how can we change the color of grid lines in Julia? I check the [docs](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/attributes_axis/), but I can only find attributes like alpha, line width and style and not the color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code to get the green grid:

```
plt = Plots.plot(rand(10))
xaxis = Plots.get_axis(Plots.get_subplot(plt,1),:x)
yaxis = Plots.get_axis(Plots.get_subplot(plt,1),:y)
xaxis[:gridalpha] = 0.6
yaxis[:gridalpha] = 0.6
xaxis[:foreground_color_grid] = colorant"green"
yaxis[:foreground_color_grid] = colorant"green"
plt
```

Many other attributes are described in the docs page you linked to.